# Initcap is not working with Special character

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm doing

```
select initcap('the /soap') from dual;
```

> result : The /Soap

But I want result to be:

> The /soap

I want my Soap 's' to be small. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initcap works that way.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions067.htm#SQLRF00650) says:

> Words are delimited by white space or characters that are not alphanumeric.

which means that "soap" is considered to be a separate word (instead of "/soap", which is what you'd want).

Workaround requires a little bit of typing, for example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'the /soap' from dual),
  3  t_split as
  4    -- split string to rows
  5    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val,
  6            level lvl
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
  9    ),
 10  t_initcap as
 11    -- apply INITCAP only to words that don't contain special characters
 12    (select case when not regexp_like(val, '[^0-9A-Za-z]') then initcap(val)
 13                 else val
 14            end valinit,
 15            lvl
 16     from t_split
 17    )
 18    -- merge them back
 19  select listagg(valinit, ' ') within group (order by lvl) result
 20  from t_initcap;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The /soap

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, an XML version that lower-cases any word (token) starting with any punctuation character in a string that has already been through `initcap`:

```
select *
from xmltable(
  'string-join(
    for $t in tokenize($s, " ") 
      return if (matches($t, "^\p{P}")) then lower-case($t) else $t,
    " ")'
  passing initcap('the /soap') as "s"
);

Result Sequence                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The /soap
```

And one that replaces the `initcap` call:

```
select *
from xmltable(
  'string-join(
    for $t in tokenize($s, " ") 
      return concat(upper-case(substring($t, 1, 1)), lower-case(substring($t, 2))),
    " ")'
  passing 'the /soap' as "s"
);

Result Sequence                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The /soap
```

Comment: For you, it is fun. For me, it is science fiction.